# Processing applying different textures/images to cubes

Tags: java, image, textures, processing, cube

I'm currently working on a Processing Project for school. I'm a bit of a noob so sorry if my code is a little messy! I'm having a hard time applying different textures to different cubes. I'm trying to apply the textures with an array but I'm not sure if its the correct way. There are comments but don't mind them. Please help a brother out! Thanks

Here is my main class:

```
float rotx = PI/4;
float roty = PI/4;
float bounds = 300;

Cube[] cubies = new Cube[5];

int maxImages = 3;
int imageIndex = 0;

PImage[] images = new PImage[maxImages];

void setup() {
size(640, 360, P3D);
/*tex = loadImage("image0.jpg");
tex2 = loadImage("image1.jpg");
tex3 = loadImage("image2.jpg");*/



//imageIndex = int(random(images.length));

for (int i = 0; i < cubies.length; i++) {
// Cubies are randomly sized
float cubieSize = random(15, 55);
cubies[i] =  new Cube(cubieSize, cubieSize, cubieSize);
 for (int j = 0; j<images.length; j ++) {
  images[j] = loadImage("image" + j + ".jpg");
  texture(images[j]);
 }
}


}

void draw() {
/*background(0);
noStroke();
//translate(width/2.0, height/2.0, -100);

scale(90);
//Cube();*/
background(50);
lights();
rotateX(rotx);
rotateY(roty);

// Center in display window
translate(width/2, height/2, -130);

// Rotate everything, including external large cube
rotateX(frameCount * 0.001);
rotateY(frameCount * 0.002);
rotateZ(frameCount * 0.001);
stroke(255);


for(Cube c : cubies){
c.display();
c.update();
}
}


void mouseDragged() {
float rate = 0.01;
rotx += (pmouseY-mouseY) * rate;
roty += (mouseX-pmouseX) * rate;
}
```

Here is my Cube class:

```
class Cube {

PVector position;
PVector velocity;
// Also using PVector to hold rotation values for 3 axes
PVector rotation;

// Vertices of the cube
PVector[] vertices = new PVector[24];
// width, height, depth
float w, h, d;






Cube(float w, float h, float d) {
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
this.d = d;



textureMode(NORMAL);
fill(255);
stroke(color(44, 48, 32));


// Start in center
position = new PVector();
// Random velocity vector
velocity = PVector.random3D();
// Random rotation
rotation = new PVector(random(40, 100), random(40, 100), random(40, 100));



vertices[0] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2, d/2);
vertices[1] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2, d/2);
vertices[2] = new PVector(w/2, h/2, d/2);
vertices[3] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2, d/2);
//left
vertices[4] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2, d/2);
vertices[5] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2, -d/2);
vertices[6] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2, -d/2);
vertices[7] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2, d/2);
//right
vertices[8] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2, d/2);
vertices[9] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2, -d/2);
vertices[10] = new PVector(w/2, h/2, -d/2);
vertices[11] = new PVector(w/2, h/2, d/2);
//back
vertices[12] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2, -d/2); 
vertices[13] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2, -d/2);
vertices[14] = new PVector(w/2, h/2, -d/2);
vertices[15] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2, -d/2);
//top
vertices[16] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2, d/2);
vertices[17] = new PVector(-w/2, -h/2, -d/2);
vertices[18] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2, -d/2);
vertices[19] = new PVector(w/2, -h/2, d/2);
//bottom
vertices[20] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2, d/2);
vertices[21] = new PVector(-w/2, h/2, -d/2);
vertices[22] = new PVector(w/2, h/2, -d/2);
vertices[23] = new PVector(w/2, h/2, d/2);
endShape();
}

void drawCube() {
// Draw cube
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
  beginShape(QUADS);
  for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {

    vertex(vertices[j+4*i].x, vertices[j+4*i].y, vertices[j+4*i].z);
  }
  endShape();
}
}
 // Update location
 void update() {
 position.add(velocity);

// Check wall collisions
if (position.x > bounds/2 || position.x < -bounds/2) {
  velocity.x*=-1;
}
if (position.y > bounds/2 || position.y < -bounds/2) {
  velocity.y*=-1;
}
if (position.z > bounds/2 || position.z < -bounds/2) {
  velocity.z*=-1;
 }
}



 void display() {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(position.x, position.y, position.z);
  rotateX(frameCount*PI/rotation.x);
  rotateY(frameCount*PI/rotation.y);
  rotateZ(frameCount*PI/rotation.z);
  noStroke();
  drawCube(); // Farm out shape to another method
  popMatrix();
}
}
```

EDIT: added code for a cube with multiple textures (as requested).
[here is the final result of this class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNlut.jpg)

```
float rotx = PI/4;
float roty = PI/4;

int maxImages = 3;
int imageIndex = 0;

PImage[] images = new PImage[maxImages];
//PImage img = createImage(50,50,RGB);



void setup() {
size(640, 360, P3D);
/*tex = loadImage("image0.jpg");
tex2 = loadImage("image1.jpg");
tex3 = loadImage("image2.jpg");*/

for(int i = 0; i<images.length; i ++){
images[i] = loadImage("image" + i + ".jpg");
}
//imageIndex = int(random(images.length));

textureMode(NORMAL);
fill(255);
stroke(color(44,48,32));
}

 void draw() {
 background(0);
 noStroke();
 translate(width/2.0, height/2.0, -100);
 rotateX(rotx);
 rotateY(roty);
 scale(90);
 TexturedCube(); 
 }

 void TexturedCube() {
 beginShape(QUADS);
 texture(images[0]);


// +Z "front" face
vertex(-1, -1,  1, 0, 0);
vertex( 1, -1,  1, 1, 0);
vertex( 1,  1,  1, 1, 1);
vertex(-1,  1,  1, 0, 1);
endShape();

// -Z "back" face
vertex( 1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
vertex(-1, -1, -1, 1, 0);
vertex(-1,  1, -1, 1, 1);
vertex( 1,  1, -1, 0, 1);
beginShape(QUADS);
texture(images[1]);

// +Y "bottom" face
vertex(-1,  1,  1, 0, 0);
vertex( 1,  1,  1, 1, 0);
vertex( 1,  1, -1, 1, 1);
vertex(-1,  1, -1, 0, 1);
// -Y "top" face
vertex(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
vertex( 1, -1, -1, 1, 0);
vertex( 1, -1,  1, 1, 1);
vertex(-1, -1,  1, 0, 1);

// +X "right" face
vertex( 1, -1,  1, 0, 0);
vertex( 1, -1, -1, 1, 0);
vertex( 1,  1, -1, 1, 1);
vertex( 1,  1,  1, 0, 1);

// -X "left" face
vertex(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
vertex(-1, -1,  1, 1, 0);
vertex(-1,  1,  1, 1, 1);
vertex(-1,  1, -1, 0, 1);

endShape();
}

void mouseDragged() {
float rate = 0.01;
rotx += (pmouseY-mouseY) * rate;
roty += (mouseX-pmouseX) * rate;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What exactly does this code do?

Comment: i am not able to apply textures to my cubes. This code draws 5 white cubes in the screen randomly. I want them to have an image as texture.

Comment: I would start much smaller if I were you. Can you draw a single image? Once you get that working, can you draw a single cube textured with that single image? Work your way up and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the exact step you're stuck on- it's much easier to help that way than if you post your entire sketch taking on your big end goal.

Comment: I already did those things, I'm stuck at the point where I apply different textures to different cubes.. I can apply different textures to different sides of the cube but that's not what I intend. I will edit my post and post my code for the multiple textured cube.